Is there any USB Serial communication package for IOS device using Flutter?
I am looking for a flutter package that will enable serial communication for IOS devices I have tried usb_serial package for Android devices it works well but i am not sure that this package works on IOS device since I don't have one. Anyone have idea ?
Need a flutter package that will enable USB serial communication on IOS devices.

This all depends on what you're trying to do. If you're trying to connect a custom device/cable with your iOS device and have that device read it, it won't work.
The issue for USB serial communication for iOS devices is related to the pins (the pins on the Physical cable).
Apple has a requirement where in order for your cable to be recognized for USB you must register it with Apple, which can cost anywhere around 10KUSD.
Unfortunately Apple doesn't provide allot of options, unless you Jailbreak.
There are workarounds, such as providing users with a MacOS tool (custom app) which will handle all the USB work, and can then relay the file data to your backend, that the app can then synchronise.
Basically the iOS device will send the IDs of the records you are trying to upload, then the MacOS will read the IDs from your backend, read the files via USB and then upload the data to the backend.
If you have a websocket that your iOS can connect to, it can then sync and destroy the records so the users know that their data has been synced with the backend.
